# Speed up an sqlite3 database search

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I"m new to databases and just wrote my first code using `sqlite3`. It does the job, but is running extremely slowly and I'm hoping to get some advice regarding how to speed things up.

Right now my code looks something like this:

```
For Line in File:
   Line= Line.strip('\n').split('\n')
   Location = int(Line[1])
   MChr = Line[0]
cur = db.execute('''SELECT Start, End, Chr, Feature1, Feature2, Feature3, Feature4, FROM DataBase
                    WHERE Start <= ? AND End >= ? AND Chr == ?''', (Location, Location, MChr))
for (Start, Stop, Chr, Feature1, Feature2, Feature3, Feature4) in cur:
    if Feature1 == "A string":
        do something....
    if Feature2 == "A string":
        do something....
```

My database is a little over one million entries which is probably why my program is running slow but I was wondering if there is a way to make the search more efficient to circumvent having to run through all million for every line. (Perhaps first pull out all matching Chrs?)

Comment: Have you tried using indexes yet?

Comment: as an aside, please read the [python style guidelines](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Upper case names are for classes, code is a lot easier to read if it conforms to public expectations.

Answer (score 2):

You should index your db:

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html

This should speed things up.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking into how to create indexes right now but was wondering how it works - do I create the index on the orignal database/table or recreate it every tiem I run a comparison? Also the Chr column has several strings that repeat in many of the entries. Do I create a regular index or unique index? And once the index is created how can I specifically search using it?

Comment: Create the index right after you create the table. So that means only once (you can then `describe MyTable;` and it will show up in the `Key` column.) Afterwards, do the searches just as you did before.

Comment: @user2165857: You should create regular indexes, unless you really know that those columns contain unique data on every row. Unique indexes are mainly for primary keys, which I don't think it's the case here.

Answer (score 1):

Create indexes on the columns in question. If your table name is `DataBase`, then try something like:

```
db.execute('''CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Start_index ON `DataBase` (`Start`(64))''')
db.execute('''CREATE UNIQUE INDEX End_index ON `DataBase` (`End`(64))''')
db.execute('''CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Chr_index ON `DataBase` (`Chr`(64))''')
```

Comment: What does (64) stand for? Also I keep getting the following error: `cur.execute('''CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Start_index ON `Ensembl` (`Start`(64))''')
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error`